# How does inheritance of ssl directives from sibling blocks work in nginx configs?

Tags: nginx

We have an `nginx` config that works as a front-end for a number of separate services, mainly to do SSL decap.  It is pointed to by DNS entries for `example.com` and `*.example.com`, and we route traffic to certain specific `service.example.com` to backends running on other ports on the same machine, using the following config (simplified):

```
# Main server.  Handles all traffic not for specific subdomains.
server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7780/;
  }
}

server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name service1.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7781/;
  }
}

server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name service2.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7782/;
  }
}

# Etc. for several more
```

This config has been arrived at by trial and error and seems to work fine, but I have several (closely related) questions about it:

- Why do we not need to respecify the `ssl_certificate*` directives for the second and subsequent `server` blocks?  (I though directives were not supposed to be inherited from sibling blocks.)
- Why does repeating the `ipv6only=off` option on the second and subsequent `server_name` directives causes `nginx` to reject the config with "`[emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wildcard:14`?
- Conversely, why is it acceptable (but not required!) to repeat the `ssl` option?
- <strike>In fact, replacing the second and subsequent `listen` directives with `listen 443;` seems to work just as well.  Is there any reason not to do that?</strike>

Basically: wat?  Are there any general rules about which directives/options are inherited from sibling blocks, and which not?

Answer (score 0):

Directives are not inherited from sibling blocks, something else is going on.
Check your http section, does that have duplicative SSL settings in it? SSL can be in the HTTP context block too.

for example I have all my SSL settings at the top of the http {} section with a wild card cert defined. This then applies to the root domain and all subdomains without me having to respecify.  Another way do it is to put all your ssl settings in a include file and use include directive to load inside the server or location section.

Alternatively are you sure your other servers are not connecting using that first server block....

I am not sure why you see the ipv6only=off issue, the docs seem to indicate it can only be set once per start and applies to [::] as such i think it is a global setting.

BTW the 'normal' way to specify you want both IPV6 and IPv4 is to use this:

```
server {
    server_name             server.mydomain.tld;
    listen                  443 ssl http2;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
```

the http2 is optional, but i have it on for all my servers.

Comment: The only ssl options set directly in the `http` section are `ssl_protocols` and `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers`.  It seems obvious that `ssl_certificate` directives must apply to all `server` sections on the same port, because the SSL certificate has to be chosen before the `Host` header is sent; I just want to know what the rules are for the other directives/options.

Answer (score -1):

The reason not to specify subsequent `server` blocks with `listen 443;` is `nginx` will *reload* the configuration just fine, but the next time it *restarts* it will complain "`nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)`" once for every `server` section listening on 443.

Comment: Note: complains N time, not N-1 times, for N `server` blocks.  Wat?  How can the socket be already bound the first time?